# NodeJS Promise and Symbol.species usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I trying to subclass the standard promise object, but I want `then` to return a standard promise object not my subclass.

```
class CustomPromise extends Promise
{
    constructor(fn)
    {
        super(fn);
    }

    static get [Symbol.species]()
    {
        console.log("get Symbol.species");
        return Promise;
    }

    toString()
    {
        return "CustomPromise";
    }
}

var p = new CustomPromise((resolve) => resolve(5)).then(v => console.log(v) );
console.log(p.toString());
```

That works fine with chrome were I see:

```
test4.js:12 get Symbol.species
test4.js:25 [object Promise]
```

But doesn't seems to work with NodeJS

```
node ~/Documents/test4.js 
CustomPromise
```

Is this a NodeJS bug ? any ideas how to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing, Node does not yet support `Symbol.species`.

```
> 'species' in Symbol
false
```

It is currently behind a flag (`--harmony-species` or `--es-staging`) in v6.x. So it *may* work if you start Node like this:

```
$ node --es-staging
> 'species' in Symbol
true
```

I'll note that your particular example does work in Node v6.3.1 with that flag. It's just not yet shipping in Node, and won't likely in the latest version until the next major version bump.